# R dataframe to JSON questions

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below

```
testdf <- data.frame(timestamp=c("2015-07-22T02:00:00", "2015-07-22T03:00:00", "2015-07-22T04:00:00"), PM2.5=c(25.48, 25.09, 26.26), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> testdf
            timestamp PM2.5
1 2015-07-22T02:00:00 25.48
2 2015-07-22T03:00:00 25.09
3 2015-07-22T04:00:00 26.26
```

I want a JSON Format as below.

```
{
  "data":[{"timestamp": "2015-07-22T02:00:00", "value": {"PM2.5": 25.48}},
          {"timestamp": "2015-07-22T03:00:00", "value": {"PM2.5": 25.09}},
          {"timestamp": "2015-07-22T04:00:00", "value": {"PM2.5": 26.26}}]
}
```

So I try to covert my Target JSON to dataframe to observed how the dataframe like

```
    json <- '{
          "data":[{"timestamp": "2015-07-22T02:00:00", "value": {"PM2.5": 25.48}},
                  {"timestamp": "2015-07-22T03:00:00", "value": {"PM2.5": 25.09}},
                  {"timestamp": "2015-07-22T04:00:00", "value": {"PM2.5": 26.26}}]
        }'

tmp <- fromJSON(json)
> tmp
$data
            timestamp PM2.5
1 2015-07-22T02:00:00 25.48
2 2015-07-22T03:00:00 25.09
3 2015-07-22T04:00:00 26.26
```

I then convert my testdf  to look like tmp

```
> testL <- list(testdf)
> names(testL) <- c("data")
> testL
$data
            timestamp PM2.5
1 2015-07-22T02:00:00 25.48
2 2015-07-22T03:00:00 25.09
3 2015-07-22T04:00:00 26.26
```

Well, it look same, but for some reason, when I using toJSON on 
testL, it missing a "value":, but as you see, using the same
toJSON(tmp) is good, See below

```
 > toJSON(testL)
{"data":[{"timestamp":"2015-07-22T02:00:00","PM2.5":25.48},{"timestamp":"2015-07-22T03:00:00","PM2.5":25.09},{"timestamp":"2015-07-22T04:00:00","PM2.5":26.26}]} 
> 
> toJSON(tmp)
{"data":[{"timestamp":"2015-07-22T02:00:00","value":{"PM2.5":25.48}},{"timestamp":"2015-07-22T03:00:00","value":{"PM2.5":25.09}},{"timestamp":"2015-07-22T04:00:00","value":{"PM2.5":26.26}}]}
```

The reason might be as below, when I unlist tmp and testL, I observed
unlist(tmp) is "data.value.PM2.51"  and unlist(testL) is data.PM2.51

```
> unlist(tmp)
      data.timestamp1       data.timestamp2       data.timestamp3 
"2015-07-22T02:00:00" "2015-07-22T03:00:00" "2015-07-22T04:00:00" 
    data.value.PM2.51     data.value.PM2.52     data.value.PM2.53 
              "25.48"               "25.09"               "26.26" 
> unlist(testL)
      data.timestamp1       data.timestamp2       data.timestamp3 
"2015-07-22T02:00:00" "2015-07-22T03:00:00" "2015-07-22T04:00:00" 
          data.PM2.51           data.PM2.52           data.PM2.53 
              "25.48"               "25.09"               "26.26" 
>
```

So how can I obtained the JSON file exactly the same as toJSON(tmp)

Thanks in advance! 
James

Comment: Which json package are you using?

Comment: Me too. If you are using Rstudio, you can see in the top right panel that in `tmp`, `value` is actually a list containing PM2.5. You can investigate closer using `dput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `jsonlite` package, I obtain just like you. If you look closely at the structure using `dput`, you will see that tmp and testL look the same while they aren't.

```
> dput(tmp)
structure(list(data = structure(list(timestamp = c("2015-07-22T02:00:00", 
"2015-07-22T03:00:00", "2015-07-22T04:00:00"), value = structure(list(
    PM2.5 = c(25.48, 25.09, 26.26)), .Names = "PM2.5", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L))), .Names = c("timestamp", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L))), .Names = "data")

> dput(testL)
structure(list(data = structure(list(timestamp = c("2015-07-22T02:00:00", 
"2015-07-22T03:00:00", "2015-07-22T04:00:00"), PM2.5 = c(25.48, 
25.09, 26.26)), .Names = c("timestamp", "PM2.5"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = "data")
```

A more convenient way of seeing this structure is, in Rstudio, to look in the environment panel. In short, `tmp` is a list containing `data`. `data` is a data.frame containing `timestamp` and value. `value` is a data.frame containing `PM.2.5`.

You can correct the structure of testL using

```
testL$data$value <- data.frame(PM2.5=testL$data$PM2.5)
testL$data$PM2.5 <- NULL
```

Then `jsonlite::toJSON` yields the same result for tmp and testL.

EDIT: For the posterity, note that you really should use `str` instead of `dput` to do this kind of debugging!

For example, here is what `str(tmp)` looks like:

```
List of 1
 $ data:'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ timestamp: chr [1:3] "2015-07-22T02:00:00" "2015-07-22T03:00:00" "2015-07-22T04:00:00"
  ..$ value    :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ PM2.5: num [1:3] 25.5 25.1 26.3
```

Which is much easier to read that the output of `dput`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Antoine, your solutions works as expect!